# Align iron-icon with border

Tags: css, svg, polymer

I am trying to aligning the icon inside an `iron-icon` with the border.
The border is a circle with filling and I want my svg to be in the middle.
I fixed it, but it seems hacky by moving the svg 5 px to the right.

The SVG path is the cause of the problem. It is slighty offset and gets aligned to the top and does not scale to the size of the iron-icon.

The problem does not occur if I use a `iron-icon` default icon.

Element:

```
<style>
        iron-icon {
            --iron-icon-height: 48px;
            --iron-icon-width: 48px;
            border: 10px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: var(--dark-theme-base-color);
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px var(--dark-theme-base-color);
            --iron-icon-fill-color: var(--dark-theme-text-color);
        }

        #HACKY FIX
        iron-icon ::content > .style-scope {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
</style>

<iron-icon class="circled-logo" icon="logo-icons:browse-and-buy"></iron-icon>
```

Icon set:

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="logo-icons" size="100">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100"
    xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <g id="browse-and-buy" transform="scale(3.0)">
            <path d="M13,5c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1v4.6L5.7,4.3c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4,0
                c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l6.3,6.3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h7c0.6,0,1-0.5,1-1V6C14,5.4,13.5,5,13,5z M25.7,24.3L19.4,18
                H24c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-7c-0.6,0-1,0.5-1,1v7c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1v-4.6l6.3,6.3c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0
                C26.1,25.3,26.1,24.7,25.7,24.3z"/>
        </g>

    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you give a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jacudu/edit?html,output) recreates the problem.

Comment: Yes! That jsbin perfectly recreates the problem. Thank you Tony19. The hacky fix does not work in the example.